# Should the mean energy be written in angular brackets or with an overline?

Tags: energy, notation

How would you write mean energy? I came up with two different ways:

- $\displaystyle\langle G_{\textrm{f}}^\circ(j) \rangle$ with the MathJax code `\langle G_{\textrm{f}}^\circ(j) \rangle`
- $\displaystyle\overline{G}_{\textrm{f}}^\circ(j)$ with the MathJax code `\overline{G}_{\textrm{f}}^\circ(j)`
- Or maybe another way?

I am looking for the proper use of this notation in the scientific literature.

Comment: When in doubt, simply indicate what you mean in text.

Comment: To the question itself: I believe that the bar notation is most common for point values, while the bracket notation is mainly for functions. In any case I would write $\displaystyle \overline{G_{\textrm{f}}^\circ(j)}$.

Comment: Depends on the convention used. Different people use different conventions but both indicate a mean.

Comment: I would use \overline for representing arithmetic mean, and \langle \rangle for  expected value (notice that their difference is commonly overlooked in chemistry literature). However, the proper use only requires  stating the meaning in text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both the [IUPAC 2008 Green Book](https://www.iupac.org/fileadmin/user_upload/publications/e-resources/ONLINE-IUPAC-GB3-2ndPrinting-Online-Sep2012.pdf) (section 4.2) as well as the [ACS Style Guide](https://doi.org/10.1021/bk-2006-STYG) (specifically [Chapter 11](https://doi.org/10.1021/bk-2006-STYG.ch011)) agree that both methods of representing the mean value are acceptable. There might be some style guides / international standards that state otherwise, but for the average chemist these two are generally sufficient.

If ever in doubt, just state the meaning in text.

Comment: The international standard ISO 80000-2 _Quantities and units – Part 2: Mathematical signs and symbols to be used in the natural sciences and technology_ agrees.

Comment: Good to know, too. I was lazy to check, hence the disclaimer.